# Merge 2 json on coincident key

Tags: javascript, performance

I have 2 json objects:

First one:

```
 [
{
"id":"4503",
"Province":["Alicante"],
"Type":["Full Proffesor"],
"Description":["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"]
}]
```

Second one:

```
[{
"id":"4503",
"weight": 3200,
}]
```

I want to combine both, so I finally get:

```
 [
{
"id":"4503",
"Province":["Alicante"],
"Type":["Full Proffesor"],
"Description":["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"],
"weight": 3200
}]
```

This is what I did:

```
var originalJson = JSON.parse(originalData);
var moreJson = JSON.parse(moreData);
for(var i=0; i < originalJson.length; i++){
       var id = originalJson[i]["id"];
       for(var j = 0; j < moreJson.length; j++){
           if(moreJson[j]["id"] == id){
               originalJson[i]["weight"] = moreJson[i]["weight"];
                break;
           }
       }
 }
```

In this example there is only one element in each JSON (both with id=4503) but I'm working with hundreds of them. They are a response of different aplications, and they are not ordered in the same way, and they may have different lenght:

> originalJson.lenght != moreJson.length
>
> originalJson[0] != moreJson[0]

This is fine with only one element in the JSON, but when there are hundreds it starts to be more complicated.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Presumably you meant your code to say : if(moreJson[j]["id"] == id) and  originalJson[i]["weight"] = moreJson[j]["weight"]? But it seems you've answered your own question. What is the problem with your current method?

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery.Extend? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: You can `splice` the element out of `moreJSON` every time you found a match; that may reduce some time.

Comment: @urbananimal you're right with both, I corrected de 'id' issue, but you answered really fast :)

My own answer is right, but it is not very efficient, there must be a better way!

Comment: @Passerby I tryed to do `delete` but some unexpected behaviour happened. I will try with `splice` thanks :D

Comment: I don't think there is a better way like @Passerby said you can splice the items out of the second list so you're not searching obsolete items (you'd have to change your for loop to a while loop though) but it think the general process you're doing is right. Passerby should post that as an answer.

Comment: @MattCooper including jQuery just so as you can add 1 property to object is probably not a great idea. The question is really about the best way to find related items in 2 unrelated lists.